# django rest framework: filter many to many models

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-oscar

I have a product model, category model and a product_category model for storing the product id to multiple categories.

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('Slug'), max_length=255, unique=False)

class Category(models.Model):   
    name = models.SlugField(_('Slug'), max_length=255, unique=False)

class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('catalogue.Product', verbose_name=_("Product"))
    category = models.ForeignKey('catalogue.Category', verbose_name=_("Category"))
```

My serializers.py

```
class MyProductLinkCustomSerializer(ProductLinkSerializer):

class Meta(ProductLinkSerializer.Meta):
    fields = ('url', 'id', 'product_id', 'title',)
```

views.py

```
class ProductListCustom(basic.ProductList):
    def get_queryset(self):
        category_id = self.request.query_params.get('category_id', None)
        #filter products with this category_id, if someone provided category_id in url

        return Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyProductLinkCustomSerializer
```

I want to list the products with category object for each product belongs to. Also I want to filter the products by the category_id it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you should consider: using models.ManyToManyField to link category and product.

```
class Product(models.Model):    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('Slug'), max_length=255, unique=False)

    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='products')
```

Then, you can filter products like this:

```
Product.objects.filter(categories=category_id)
```

here is some [useful example for ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)